# How to change default sms application background in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-intent, sms

I am creating an app based on sms functionality, But I am stuck at one point where i want to set background image to default sms app in android.

How can i achieve this...?

A sample code or link will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Do you want to change Background of Default sms app, or want to change your app backgroud similar to Default SMS APP

Comment: change Background of Default sms app...!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible until you are doing Customization of Android OS.

> > Will you prefer someone else application changing background of your application??

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @ankit but in my case someone else application logic will be considerable....!